# Getting error when submitting to app store

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]Getting this error when in the process of submitting to app store.

I have Distribution Profile in my dev account

Comment: Remove your apple account from xcode preferences and re add so that it downloads all the profiles again. @Droppy fixed it, sorry.

Comment: thanks ill try it out, also should i change my provisional profile in xcode from automatic to the distribution?

Comment: @Shubhank i removed it and readded my account, issue still exisits.